# How to set a value with two digit precision using Matlab

Tags: matlab

The variable Ge can get  values such as 0.0233356 or 0.123. 
How to set this value to have only two digit precision each time?

```
set (handles.boxGe,'String',Ge );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Ge` is a numeric value, you can use `num2str` to convert it to a string. You set the precision via the argument.

```
Ge = 0.0233356;
Ge_str = num2str( Ge, '%.2f')
set (handles.boxGe,'String',Ge_str );
```

Answer (score 0):

Display a number with two digits behind the dot:

```
fprintf('%.2f', pi)
```

Comment: I cannot understand what i should modify in order to set the value in boxGe from your answer. Could u explain me more?